# Windows 10 Creative Update, Game mode missing

Tags: windows-10-v1703

Last night I updated to the new Windows 10 Creative Update in anticipation for accessing the new Game Mode, but its not there.

I updated at work too and there I have the section so I know what's in it and where it is, but on my powerful pc at home, its missing.

What can I do to get it back?

I'm using Windows 10 Pro N. Could that be the reason?

EDIT: I just finished updating another one of my computers, also running Windows 10 Pro N, and its lacking the Game icon too. Seems like a bug in the update where they forgot to patch it for Windows 10 Pro N...

[image]

Comment: Screenshot, just for curiousity?

Comment: I can't see any reason why it might be missing. Are you certain the upgrade succeeded?  Can you post the output of running `winver`?

Comment: look in settings app, here you should see a blue XBox Icon, this includes game mode settings

Comment: @magicandre1981 if you read my question, you realize I know exactly where it should be, but it isn't there.

Comment: @Mokubai Added images per request. I am sure the upgrade succeeded because I do have the Night mode, another feature I wanted.

Comment: Okay, so you are right and it is the right version but your "Gaming" settings is missing from your Settings panel which is where the Game mode setting should be.  I can see it on my machine so I'm curious why it is missing. Have you launched the Xbox app at all? (which is where most of the setting in that menu were originally) What graphics does your machine have?

Comment: @Mokubai I may need to reinstall the Media feature pack and maybe then it works. The xbox app complains its missing too... Graphicscard is an ATI HD 7950, running on an AMD Athlon FX 8230.

Comment: @Mokubai okay, just checked... Installing the Media Feature Pack and then rebooting does not make Xbox app work, nor does the Game Mode DVR option show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I feared, this is due to the installation being windows 10 Pro N.

Windows 10 Pro N is the same as Pro, without the Media Feature pack. This pack includes things as Media player, skype, codecs and other stuff.

In order to make Game Mode working, you need to install the [Media Feature Pack](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3010081/media-feature-pack-for-windows-10-n-and-windows-10-kn-editions), which will indeed make the Windows 10 Pro N the same as Windows 10 Pro.

Each Major update/version of windows has a different pack. You can find a list with downloads [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3145500/media-feature-pack-list-for-windows-n-editions).

To directly download the [Media Feature Pack v1703](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4016817/media-feature-pack-for-n-edition-of-windows-10-version-1703-april-2017), click [this link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4016817/media-feature-pack-for-n-edition-of-windows-10-version-1703-april-2017)

Comment: The media pack you linked to is for 1511 not 1703

Comment: [Here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3133719/media-feature-pack-for-n-editions-of-windows-10-version-1607) is the correct Media Pack.  How I read that statement is different, I read it as that Game DVR, won't work until the media pack is installed.

Comment: @Ramhound I linked to that page due to the features, but your link is also incorrect: "Media Feature Pack for N editions of Windows 10 Version 1607". Anyway, I did install the right pack, otherwise it will not install, I know that from experience, but no luck. It still doesn't work.

Comment: Wow, alright, so I will link to the page with the link, to the correct version when it's submitted :-) [Here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3145500/media-feature-pack-list-for-windows-n-editions)

Comment: [Here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/media-feature-pack-n-for-build-1703/5534d522-e4ae-4f55-aa48-603aaa8e898e?tab=question&status=AllReplies) says it will be next week

Comment: @Ramhound thanks. Updated the answer. Will test it next week when the new version is up and if that fixes things I'll edit the answer once more.

Comment: Yep; Like I said I might be wrong, I don't have that version, but I read the disclaimer a little different (game dvr doesn't work without the pack because the lack of video decoders) but Microsoft was forced to offer those editions so who knows what brokenb because of them

Comment: @Ramhound Actually, at the top it starts with: exceptiosn. I read it in, well this will not fix the following.... Rereading the page once more, I see where you're coming from. Lets hope it works. :)

Comment: And confirmed! Installing the correct Media Feature Pack fixes the issue.

Comment: Trust me; Speaking Microsoft is a difficult skill to pick up :-)

Comment: @Ramhound It seems so. xD

Comment: @LFChip The alien cows had an easier language to understand.  Ask me about it sometime in chat, and I explain my comment :-)

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft released the Media Feature Pack for the Creators Update and yes, it fixes the issue we're having: it adds Game Mode!

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4016817/media-feature-pack-for-n-edition-of-windows-10-version-1703-april-2017

Comment: From the linked page, "Effects on other features - Webcam: This feature does not work." Wait what?