# Windows Media Player Missing after Creators Update

Tags: windows-10, windows-media-player, windows-10-v1703

My copy of Windows 10 N Professional recently installed the "Creators Update", and after rebooting, Windows Media Player is missing and no videos will play on my web browser.

How can I restore this functionality?

Comment: @Ramhound - Please note that feature updates to Windows 10 count as full OS updates, so the Media Feature Pack for the Anniversary Update does NOT work with the Creators Update. Therefore not a dup.

Comment: I am more then aware of that fact, but the answer is actually the same, you have to install the media pack.  I don't think every feature update justifies a new question about the media pack honestly.  Could have link to the question with my broader answer which points to each feature update media pack if I wanted to.

Comment: Related question: https://superuser.com/questions/1141980/cannot-download-correct-version-of-windows-media-feature-pack-icloud-outlook-s/1142024#1142024 and https://superuser.com/questions/1196713/windows-10-creative-update-game-mode-missing?rq=1

Comment: @Ramhound - I figured there would be a more generic answer but couldn't find it. Thanks for the link. Nothing came up in the search because the questions you link either point to an older version of Win10 or because they're specific scenarios.

Comment: Interestingly, I've never seen the per-Windows list of MFP downloads, which is enormously useful. Searching for these updates is such an unnecessary pain in the ass.

Comment: I don't know how new the article is but I easily found it, in fact, answer led most of the media pack questions about Windows 10 and updated my existing Anderson to not only list all previous media packs but just know updated mine to include that article link.

Comment: For what's it worth, while I think this question is a duplicate, I upvoted your answer for being accurate (before the edit) so don't think I disagree with your answer

Comment: The Creators Update is NRFM.  It is for testing new features and is not intended to be the entire new system.  Once the new features are validated then it becomes a RTM candidate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows N and KN editions come without Media software due to regulatory requirements in the European Union (N) and in South Korea (KN). Every time a Windows 10 feature update comes out (e.g. Anniversary Update, Creators Update), you are required to download and re-install the Windows Media Feature Pack.

For the Windows 10 Creators Update (v1703), you can download the latest Media Feature Pack from the Microsoft website here:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4016817/media-feature-pack-for-n-edition-of-windows-10-version-1703-april-2017

Once downloaded, a Standalone Windows Update Installer will run and (re)install Windows Media Player. Once finished, the installer will ask you to restart. Once your system has rebooted, you should find Window Media Player back in your Start Menu.

As per [this](https://superuser.com/a/1142024/25271) answer by Ramhound, the full list of Media Feature Packs can be found [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3145500/media-feature-pack-list-for-windows-n-editions), organised by Windows version. Note that you do NOT need to download all of them, just the one for the version of Windows you are using.

Comment: It gets worse! According to [this slashdot post](https://news.slashdot.org/story/17/10/09/1927208/windows-10-update-removes-windows-media-player) dated Oct 09, 2017 update KB4046355 removes Media Player. To get it back you have to go to Settings > Apps and Features > Manage Optional Features and add it from there.